# Owl carousel swiping slides makes element taller

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddnKA.png)

[image]

The incoming slides being scrolled change height, but then snap back to the height the are supposed to be, only while scrolling.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 4,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 4,
        nav: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
        nav: false
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5,
        nav: true
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 240px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: black;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: red;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: green;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: blue;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: purple;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: orange;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: black;"> Your Content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using min-height and max-height did not work either

Comment: Could you explain little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ 
    //Autoplay
    autoPlay : true,
    goToFirst : true,
    goToFirstSpeed : 1000,
    loop: true,
    items: 4,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 4,
        nav: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
        nav: false
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5,
        nav: true
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 240px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Basic stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css">
 
<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css">
 
<!-- You can use latest version of jQuery  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
 
<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: black;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: red;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: green;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: blue;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: purple;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: orange;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: black;"> Your Content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but it isn't looping, it stops on the last slide